# Stellung von "auch"

Tags: word-usage

Könnte mir bitte jemand erklären, **warum** die Stellung von auch am Ende des Satzes im ersten Beispiel geht, aber im Zweiten nicht?

> Ich mag auch Frauen. (das geht)
> Ich mag Frauen auch. (das geht auch)
>
> Ich habe auch ein Fahrrad (das geht)
> Ich habe ein Fahrrad auch (das geht aber nicht)

Comment: Es scheint, als ginge es auch mit einem bestimmten, nicht aber mit einem unbestimmten Artikel. Und das *auch* am Ende bezieht sich notwendig auf das *ich*, das in der Mitte kann sich auf beides beziehen. Bin ich froh, dass ich Muttersprachler bin!

Comment: An dem Artikel kann es nicht liegen. In allen vier Beispielen ist der Artikel unbestimmt – es ist nur so, daß er im Plural zu einem „“ verkümmert. „Ich habe Fahrräder auch“ klingt denn auch genauso schroh wie „Ich habe ein Fahrrad auch“. „Ich mag Fahrräder auch“ geht hingegen wunderbar. Also muß es am Verb liegen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich glaube, der Unterschied liegt darin, dass das Verb im zweiten Fall besitzanzeigend ist.

#### Frauen mögen

Wie Carsten in seinem Kommentar schon erwähnt hat, kann sich der Sinn des Satzes ändern, je nachdem wo das *auch* steht.

> Ich mag auch Frauen.

Bedeutet, dass in der Menge aller Dinge die ich mag, auch **Frauen** enthalten sind. (Ich mag Autos, Geld und Frauen).

> Ich mag Frauen auch.

Bedeutet, dass von allen Dingen die ich Frauen gegenüber empfinde (oder ihnen gegenüber ausübe), **mögen** eine davon ist.

*Beide* Fälle können auch bedeuten, dass in der Gruppe von Personen die Frauen mögen, auch **ich** enthalten bin. (Du und ich, wir mögen Frauen).

#### Fahrräder haben

*Haben* ist als Hilfsverb natürlich gleich verdächtig. Das Problem tritt allerdings mit *besitzen* in gleicher Form auf. Auch der Singular ist hier nicht das Entscheidende.

> Ich besitze auch Fahrräder.
>   Ich besitze Fahrräder auch.

Man kann das Beispiel mit vielen passenden Verben durchgehen: polieren, restaurieren, verkaufen, es passt immer in das Schema, das oben bei *mögen* beschrieben wurde. Sobald es um den Besitz geht, funktioniert es nicht mehr.

Ich vermute, dass bei der Anzeige von Besitz, gleich klar ist, dass ich das beschriebene Objekt besitze *und*, dass ich somit auch in der Gruppe der Besitzenden bin. Würde nur noch der Fall übrig bleiben meine Tätigkeit dem Objekt gegenüber zusammenzufassen. Besitzen ist aber keine Tätigkeit, daher kommt der Fall nicht zur Anwendung und ist im Sprachgebrauch nicht auffindbar.