# Can the position of "auch" change the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: adverb, word-order

Am I correct that the position of *auch* can give different meanings to a sentence? For example:

1. > Ich bin auch groß.

   means:

   > I have some qualities, one of which is that I am tall.
2. > Ich auch bin groß.

   means:

   > I too am tall. (Talking about some other tall person.)

   Does that make sense?
3. Would

   > Auch ich bin groß.

   be correct and if so, which meaning would it have?

Comment: 1: imho correct 2: This is not a good sentence in German. The word order is wrong. 3: This you should use for saying what you meant for sentence number 2.

Comment: Closely related, [almost duplicate](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9262/stellung-von-auch).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second sentence is not correct in german. But …

In your first sentence, *auch* refers to *what adjectives could describe you.*

> Ich bin intelligent und schnell. Ich bin *auch* groß.

However, this syntax can also be used for the following purpose:

In your third sentence, *Auch* refers to *who is tall.*

> John ist groß. *Auch* ich bin groß.

Comment: Hey. Good catch. It indeed can have a second meaning at position 3. I totally missed that.

Comment: Note that the different meanings of “Ich bin auch groß” may be distinguishable by emphasis: “Ich bin nicht nur intelligent und schnell, ich bin auch **groß**.” – “Nicht nur John ist groß; ich bin **auch** groß.”

Comment: I have to disagree with the first part of this answer. By default, the "auch" actually refers to the verb and I would understand a stand-alone "Ich bin auch groß" to mean that I and another person are tall. It can refer to the adjective too, but that is out of the default just like "Auch ich". You can check that by moving around constituents. "Nicht nur stark und klug, auch groß bin ich." You can interpret the first example that way but it is not the default and you need a specific stress pattern to communicate that (as @Wrzlprmft remarked)

Answer (score 7):

Basically, the position of an adverb can change the meaning of the sentence. This is true for any language. Here's an example for *[only](http://www.englishpractice.com/improve/position-adverbs-2/)*.

> **Only** he lent me five cents. (= He and nobody else lent me five cents.)
>    He **only** lent me five cents. (= He only lent me the money, he didn’t do anything else.)
>    He lent me **only** five cents. (= He didn’t lend me more than five cents.)
>    He lent **only** me five cents. (i.e. to nobody else)

You can translate these sentence to German and would end up with the same result. Position matters!

However, in your examples it's a little different. First, the second example is grammatically wrong.
And then it becomes difficult. The first sentence can have two different meanings, depending on context. Considering that the tallness is compared to someone else's tallness, sentence one and three mean almost the same thing. There's a very subtle difference, that imho is hard to grasp. In my opinion, the last sentence rather puts emphasis on *ich*, e.g.,

> Du bist nicht der Einzige, der groß ist. Auch **ich** bin groß.

whereas the first sentence states just the fact *that you're tall, too*.

That said, there's a second meaning as pointed out [by Sam in the other answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/11330/1224). If you listed a few adjectives beforehand, you can add this last adjective only with *auch* being in the third position.

Comment: +1 for the examples with "only"

Answer (score 4):

To map them as closely to English as possible:

> 1 - I am tall, too.

As other answers have explained, it could mean

- "Among other attributes, I also possess tallness" (probably emphasized "Ich bin auch **groß**")

  or
- "Like the aforementioned person/thing, I also possess tallness" (proably emphasized "**Ich** bin **auch** groß"

So the English and German versions include the same ambiguity.  But both are also grammatically simpler than making it more explicit (see item 3)

> 2 - Too I am tall.

This one is broken.  I just picked an ordering that wasn't grammatically correct in English, to demonstrate how weird it also sounds in German.  (and "I am too tall" means something *entirely* different)

> 3 - I, too, am tall.

Explicitly saying that not only is that other person/thing tall, but so am I.

It's worth noting that this is grammatically a lot more complex than item 1, and so while this is much less ambiguous, you'd rarely hear a little kid saying it (in English or German) when trying to measure up to a slightly-older sibling, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Example 2 is wrong.

Example 1 can both reference the person or the adjective; it depends how you emphasize the sentence:

> **Ich** bin auch groß.
>   Ich bin **auch** groß.

Example 3 only references the person.

Answer (score 0):

You are partially correct. The meaning of `auch` can changes with its position, but it also depends on the stress.

**First Sentence**

> Ich bin *auch* groß.

Here, `auch` is an adverbial referring to `sein`. Depending on the stress in the sentence it can mean different things:

- Stress is on `groß`: "apart from other qualities I have, I'm also tall"
- Stress is on `ich` or `auch`: "apart from other people being tall, I'm tall as well"

**Third Sentence**

> *Auch* ich bin groß.

Here, `auch` is an attribute to `ich`. (Otherwise, verb would be in third position.) So, the meaning is

- "apart from other people being tall, I'm tall as well"

indepent of the stress.

**Second sentence**

This sentence is grammatically wrong. It can be read as either the first or second sentence with `auch` at the wrong place.

Comment: Wait, I would understand the first example to be the same as the second unless there is a very specific stress pattern in place (auch with a strongly rising pitch, falling back down over the course of groß)... @karoshi as it stands this should not be the accepted answer

Comment: I think the same as Emanuel. Those two are quite interchangeable. And while the third is indeed ok, it sounds kind of strange and most people I know would almost always use the first one. "Warum muss ich ins Bett gehen und die Anderen nicht? Ich bin auch groß."

Comment: @Emanuel Ah, I forgot about the stress. You're right.

Comment: @Emanuel, so it's not only about word positions, but rather also about intonation and stressed words?

Comment: @karoshi... it is the same as "nicht"... there isa default-position and if you move it around you emphasize certain things "... auch groß" is the default. As it talks about the verb it can be understood either way (referring to subject or the characteristic). "Auch ich..." not the default. Here the emphasis is put on "ich".